# setGravity after setMeasuredDimension is not work

Tags: android, textview, gravity, onmeasure

I created class `customTextView extent TextView`
and I set `textAlignment` to center.
In `onMeasure` I changed the `textview` width.

After that textview align change to left
and I used `this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);`
but it didn't change to center

Answer (score 0):

add below code in your class.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            }
   };

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.list_r);
        int imageViewHeight = imageView.getMeasuredWidth();

        int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int parentHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int final_width = parentWidth - 2*imageViewHeight;
        this.setMeasuredDimension(final_width, parentHeight);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            }
        };

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,1000);
    }
```

Comment: it' work just for first page but whene scroll page , not work

Comment: i want changed it before show screen, but this code change it after show activity